# Ionic 4 ignored notch on iPhone X and 11

Tags: iphone, angular, ionic4

On two tabs in my Ionic 4 app I have an ion-header and the contents within them safely move below the notch of the full-screen iPhones (X and 11)

[image]

On the other two tabs I do not have header content but without the ion-header the content mushes up under the notch and looks bad

[image]

I'v e been trying to get this CSS to work as suggested by other questions here on SO

```
  margin-top: constant(safe-area-inset-top);
  margin-top: env(safe-area-inset-top);
```

But if I apply that to body in global.scss it mucks up the other tabs and pushes the footer off the bottom. If I apply it to ion-content within components that make up the target tabs it doesn't see to have any effect.